# Extract nested Dataframe in loop to new dataframe

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, dictionary, merge

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tickers = ["XOM", "IBM", "COKE", "BA", "SPX"]
Start = '2010-01-01'
End = '2018-1-1'
Interval = "m"

d = {}
for i in Tickers:
    d[i] = pd.DataFrame(pdr.get_data_yahoo(i,start= Start, end=End, interval=Interval))

r = {}
for i in d:
    r[i] = pd.DataFrame(d[i].Close)
u_key = []
for i in Tickers:
    u_key.append(str(i) + "_Close")

for i in r:
    df = pd.DataFrame([i])
    df.columns = u_key
```

Everything works as desired up to the last loop. The code below is my attempt at trying to merge the columns of each dataframe into a new dataframe df. However, its not working. :(

If there is a simpler way of accomplishing the same end please point it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In this example there is only one column in each dataframe prior to the merge how would one handle the case where the dataframes contain many columns and we just want the column named "Cose" from each. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: You can simply do this: `df = pd.DataFrame(pdr.get_data_yahoo(Tickers, start= Start, end=End, interval=Interval))`

Comment: @tommy.carstensen My desired output is a dataframe with the close column from each of the five tickers so that i can run a regression on any combination of the 5 tickers

Comment: @tommy.carstensen thank you for the help

Comment: @tommy.carstensen if you would be so kind as to upvote the question it would be greatly appreciated. If you post you comment as an answer, I'd be happy to upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it avoids the need to nest the dataframe:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd

Tickers = ["XOM", "IBM", "COKE", "BA", "SPX"]
Start = '2010-01-01'
End = '2018-1-1'
Interval = "m"


df = pd.DataFrame(pdr.get_data_yahoo(Tickers, start= Start, end=End, interval=Interval))

for i in df:
    if "Close" not in i:
        del df[i]
```